# File is not loading from DocumentDirectory Path Flutter

Tags: flutter, image-loading, imagepicker

i am new to Flutter.

I build simple demo app in which user can fill simple form and once user press button then those data will save into SQLite DB.

There's only 3 content. Title, Image Path (Image saved to DocumentDirectory), Location Details.

**Add Screen**

[image]

**Listing Screen**

[image]

Below is my code to copy image to path.

```
Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 600,
    );

    if (pickedFile == null) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      _storedImage = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
    final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String relativePath = '/' +
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
        path.basename(pickedFile.path);

    String newPath = '${appDir.path}' + relativePath;
    final savedImage = await File(pickedFile.path).copy('$newPath');
    widget.onSelectImage(savedImage);
  }
```

**Listing Item Code**

```
child: Card(
    elevation: 5,
    child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: FileImage(greatPlaces.items[index].image),
        ),
        title: Text(greatPlaces.items[index].title),
        subtitle: Text(
            greatPlaces.items[index].location.address),
        onTap: () {
            print(greatPlaces.items[index].image);
            //Go to detail page...
        },
    ),
)
```

**ISSUE** ==> When i add new place and view the added place list then images are loading fine but when i stop and rerun project then i am getting below error and image is not loading.

[image]

**ERROR**

> ════════ Exception caught by image resource service
> ════════════════════════════ The following FileSystemException was
> thrown resolving an image codec: Cannot open file, path =
> '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/607FB621-ABDA-472F-8B7A-D9B1BEC4A15D/Documents/1616508266743image_picker_34814E6F-218C-48F6-BE36-C4D7949F0496-1511-0000017478AD7F14.jpg'
> (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2) When the exception
> was thrown, this was the stack
> #0      _File.open. (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9) (elided 13 frames from dart:async) Path:
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/607FB621-ABDA-472F-8B7A-D9B1BEC4A15D/Documents/1616508266743image_picker_34814E6F-218C-48F6-BE36-C4D7949F0496-1511-0000017478AD7F14.jpg ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

**I downloaded app container and confirm image exist at the same place. `greatPlaces.items[index].image` return the File**

**NOTE:** ==> **Same code working fine in Android Devices.**

it will be very helpful if someone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Path of the documents directory changes on iOS after each app update. Therefore, one can not store absolute paths to the files stored in this directory. Instead, it is required to store the relative paths and then join them with the value returned by getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() every time to access the files.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but i am getting the same document directory path on every app run. the issue is image are not loading when i run app again.

Comment: Sorry. Take a look at this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008368/unable-to-retrieve-saved-image-in-flutter-issue-reproducible-only-on-ios. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I reviews it but i already have the latest version of xCode 12.4